# How can you execute struts2 actions that need to be in the main opening JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

When accessing the website at the main (index) page it has to load information that comes through actions. I have been doing some research but I do not see really clear how to do it. Can anybody give me a hint about this?

All I have seen is through JavaScript. If there is any other way to do it I would appreciate if you can explain it.

Comment: Do you want to know that How sturts communicate to its `Action Classes`? In simple words , Which thing is executing the Action belongs to specific JSP?

Comment: No, I know how to execute an action, but I do not know how to have the main idex jsp to execute it's own needed actions to show certain collection when loaded.

Comment: Simple everything should be an action, there should be no JSPs outside of struts2's control. You're probably thinking that an action requires a Class, this is not true, anything that passes though stuts2 is an action. I would strongly advise looking into the struts2-conventions plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start your application, instead of pointing directly on a JSP like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp
```

You can point to an action which forwards on index JSP.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/
```

Web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Index.html (placed under webContent, this is just an example):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL='start.do'">
<TITLE>My application</TITLE>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

struts-config.xml

```
    <action name="start" class="com.myapp.startAction" method="init">
                <result name="success">/main.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

It can be other way to do this, specially with struts2 (for instance using an index.jsp instead of index.html as suggested by @coding_idiot). But this should work.

Comment: `<forward name="success" path="foobar">` ?

Comment: Sorry, this was struts1 format. The right code for struts 2 is <result name="success">/main.jsp</result>. I'll edit the post.

Comment: This is causing the page to refresh after every second.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Struts2` action in your `web.xml` file.Follow these steps

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Create an empty file with name `index` in my web-app folder and finally placed the following entry in my `struts.xml` file

```
<action name="index" class="welcomeAction">
     <result>/ab.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

So in this case when You will be hitting this URL www.myapp.com/myApp,its calling index action of `Struts2` and you will be able to do all `init` work for your welcome page.

Comment: I don't know if I am not completely getting your proposal... I already have an action prepared to do all the init work. What I trying to do is to execute that action while the page is loading so it has the info.

Comment: @Moises: which page you are talking about? main landing page or some other page?

Comment: @Moises: That is what I was telling you.What i suggested is that you need to define Struts2 action name in place of jsp in welcome file, so when any one hit your site, this action will be called and you can do anything you want to

Comment: that won't work. The webapp on loading, requires static resources & hence, welcome file list should point to existing resources.

Comment: @coding_idiot: I have done it in may applications and they are working perfectly fine, this is one of a common way in web-application nothing special about Struts2, by this you are just fooling container.

Comment: it didn't worked for me, strange. I tried that with tomcat 6 last time.

Comment: @coding_idiot: it worked for me...are you sure you have followed steps what I suggested

Comment: @coding_idiot it also worked for me, I tried struts2-blank app.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do :

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index"); %>
```

Assuming that you have a `index` named action defined in your struts.xml

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have things like this:

**Action:** CalcAction.action

**jsp:** Calculator.jsp

Add this line in your JSP page's head tag
e.g:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; URL='CalcAction.action'"/>`

**web.xml:**

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/Calculator.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

@kloe's answer also solves the problem but it will cause your page to refresh after every second, which in return cause overhead by calling your page after every second. No offense! Cheers!

Comment: Kloe answer is good. They go away from the welcome page, so there won't be any refreshes.

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried Kloe's answer but it was giving my refreshes, then I tried this and there was no refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Better Use Normal Servlet mapping for that index.jsp in URL Mapping it will work.

Otherwise Javascript in onload of page is another option.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to create index.jsp and then use the `<s:action name="my-welcome-action" executeResult="true"/>` tag to render the output of an action inside the jsp.  This would avoid any redirect code.

https://struts.apache.org/docs/action.html

Comment: Calling one action in another action it will overkill.

Comment: It would not be calling one action inside another.  index.jsp would be rendering as the welcome page and it would execute inside of the index.jsp.  This seems like a better approach than putting a redirect inside the index.jsp, just my opinion.